# How to add line break in a TextView

Tags: android

I am using volley to get Html content of website. I am using following code.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, sourl,

            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    String highlighted = highlighter.highlight("java", response.toString());
                    mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(highlighted));
                    //mTextView.setText(response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");

        }
    });
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

But I want to load html content of website line by line not at a time and I want to add line break at the end every line before setting it into `EditText` and I don't want to wrap word.
Current Out is shown in below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this

1) Set the width to 0dp for the `TextView` in your XML file like `android:width="0dp"`

2) Set the parents to a proper width (reccomended ) in this case `FILL_PARENT` and `WRAP_CONTENT` and use `android:layout_weight=1` for the `TextView` that needs to be wrapped.

If that does not work then try adding these attributes to the `TextView`

`android:singleLine="false"`

`android:scrollHorizontally="false"`

`android:ellipsize="none"`

You can also do this programmatically as under

```
// Get handle to TextView
TextView tv = findViewByID(R.id.text_view) ;

tv.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
tv.setSingleLine(false);
```

Comment: actually I don't wrap wrap

Comment: Post your XML file

Comment: Actually i have done by adding textView.scrollHorizontally(false);